# Implementing custom adapter within a fragment in android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-arrayadapter

I have a fragment in which I want to include a List of items. This item list must contain an image view and text view. Therefore I need a custom array adapter. 
I am familiar with custom array adapter when used with Activities. As the activity java class can just extend the custom array adapter.

Since I am using fragments now, and the fragment java class extends 'Fragment' or "List Fragment" and Java does not support multiple inheritance, how do I use my custom array adapter withing my Fragment?

Couldn't find anything helpful online. please help if you know an easy way to do this!

Comment: You'd use it just like you would in an `Activity` - instantiate it, and set it on a `ListView`. What problems are you having, exactly? I don't see how multiple inheritance is a factor, here.

Comment: If I had an activity I'd do something like this -
    class MainActivity extends CustomArrayAdapter {
      //code here to add items to list view
    }

But now I'm using Fragments therefore my Java class is - 
class mainFragment extends Fragment {
//code here 
} 

Therefore, how do I implement my custom array adapter?

Comment: That doesn't really make sense. If a class is an `Activity`, it is not, and cannot be, a `ArrayAdapter`. What _exactly_ is preventing you from using any custom `Adapter` you've used before in a `Fragment`?

Answer (score 0):

Use recycler view inside fragment and create one another class for recyclerview adapter.
Then attach the object of that class to recyclerview.
Here is how to use recyclerview : [Recyclerview - Androidhive](http://www.androidhive.info/2016/01/android-working-with-recycler-view/)

Comment: Thank you! @Juned Khatri